# Rotate kinematic bodies in box2d around some point?

Tags: box2d, andengine

Is there any way to rotate kinematic bodies around point different from body's center without using of body.setTransform() method? Because when I use setTransform() physics behavior become strange. I use andengine.

Comment: You will probably have better luck asking in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the point it rotates around change? If no, you could offset the body's shapes from the body center. Then when the body rotates, it will rotate around that point.

<s>Another idea would be to use a joint.</s> (*pointed out below)

Comment: joints can't affect kinematic bodies

Answer (score 0):

You could use equations for x and y coordinates of a circle. If you use for example code below, every touch on scene would result in **angle** decrease for 0.1, and this will result in rotation of body around point(**xCenter**, **yCenter**) with radius of **r**.

```
private float p2m = PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    angle -= 0.1;

    Vector2 vector = Vector2Pool.obtain(xCenter/p2m + (r/p2m) * Math.cos(angle), (yCenter/p2m + (r/p2m) * Math.sin(angle));
    body.setTransform(vector, angle);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(vector);
    return false;
}
```